# Is it possible to run a .exe or .bat post eclipse build?

Tags: eclipse, ide, command

I would like to know if it is possible to run a `.exe` of `.bat` file after the build complete(post build)??

[image]

I have found where to add the `command` from the above image. My doubt is ***how to call .exe or .bat from here ??***

Comment: have you tried typing in the name of the .bat or .exe?

Comment: yes @JeffUK, i tried it but it was not working

Comment: What command did you try? See also https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/163153/

Comment: @howlger i have added workspace/name.bat, but it does not work

Comment: Try: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "C:\path-to-batch\myBatch.bat"